# In my example, can I use a comma before the word "thus"?

Tags: punctuation, commas, conjunctions

> Graph 4 improves Graph 3 because it shows potentially similar outliers that occur at each birthday, thus this represents our best range of x.

Comment: You need a semicolon instead of a comma. This site has some details: http://www.sussex.ac.uk/informatics/punctuation/colonandsemi/semi

Comment: See [these related questions](http://english.stackexchange.com/search?q=comma+splice).

Answer (score 1):

The more traditional approaches:

> Graph 4 improves Graph 3 because it shows potentially similar outliers that occur at each birthday. Thus, this represents our best range of x.
>
> Graph 4 improves Graph 3 because it shows potentially similar outliers that occur at each birthday; thus, this represents our best range of x.

More detailed information can be found at [this answer](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/44369/start-a-subordinate-clause-with-thus) to *[Is it okay to start a subordinate clause with 'thus'?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/44369/start-a-subordinate-clause-with-thus)*